# Реализация игры крестики-нолики

Tags: java

Всем привет! Пишу консольную игру крестики-нолики. В перспективе - создать бота. Реализация игры: есть пронумерованное поле 3х3 от 1 до 9, в котором игроку предлагается поставить крестик или нолик путем ввода соответствующего числа. Пока я создал черновик, где ходит только крестик.
И на данный момент для меня представляется затруднительным следующее:

1. как сделать поочередный ход?
2. как установить запрет на изменение крестика на нолик и наоборот?

Спасибо!

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Введите число от 1 до 9, чтобы сделать Ваш ход: " + '\n');

        char[][] field = {{'1','2','3'},
                          {'4','5','6'},
                          {'7','8','9'}};

        boolean isWon = false;

        while (true) {

            printField(field);

            int num = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

            switch (num) {
                case 1: field[0][0] = 'x'; break;
                case 2: field[0][1] = 'x'; break;
                case 3: field[0][2] = 'x'; break;
                case 4: field[1][0] = 'x'; break;
                case 5: field[1][1] = 'x'; break;
                case 6: field[1][2] = 'x'; break;
                case 7: field[2][0] = 'x'; break;
                case 8: field[2][1] = 'x'; break;
                case 9: field[2][2] = 'x'; break;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {

                if (field[i][0] == field[i][1] && field[i][0] == field[i][2] || // сравнение по горизонтали
                    field[0][i] == field[1][i] && field[0][i] == field[2][i] || // сравнение по вертикали
                    field[0][0] == field[1][1] && field[0][0] == field[2][2] || // сравнение по
                    field[2][0] == field[1][1] && field[2][0] == field[0][2]) { // диагоналям

                    isWon = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isWon){
                System.out.println("YOU WIN!!!");
                printField(field);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printField (char[][] field) {
        for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < field[i].length; j++) {
                if (j != 2)
                    System.out.print(field[i][j] + "|");
                else System.out.print(field[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде чем писать код, надо взять карандаш, бумагу и попробовать прорисовать работу программы.

Давайте попробуем сначала. В игру крестики-нолики обычно играю два игрока, у каждого свой символ, соответственно крестик, или нолик и все это происходит на игровом поле произвольного размера.

**Игровое поле:**

```
class GameTable {
    public GameTable(int row, int col) {
        ...
    }

    // Выполнение хода игроком
    // Параметр Player player - игрок с методом player.getChip()
    // return есть ли выигрышная комбинация (true), или нет (false)
    public boolean move(Player player) {
        // Здесь игрок player выбирает не занятую/свободную ячейку и помещает 
        // на нее свою фишку player.getChip()
        return this.checkWinCombination(selectedRow, selectedColumn);
    }
    
    // Проверяет заполненность стола. Если заполнен и ходов больше сделать нельзя, 
    // то true, иначе false
    public boolean isFull() {
    }

    // Метод проверки выигрышной комбинации, начиная с заданной ячейки row, col
    private boolean checkWinCombination(int row, int col) {
        // Берем ячейку и пробегаем смежные ячейки по горизонтали,
        // вертикали и диагоналям в поисках выигрышной последовательности 
        // Если нашли, то return true
        // иначе false     
    }

}
```

**Игрок:**

```
class Player {
    // name - имя игрока
    // chip - фишка игрока
    public Player(String name, String chip) {
    }
    
    public String getName() {
    }

    public String getChip() {
    }
}
```

**Инициализация**

```
//Список игроков:
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

// Игровое поле
GameTable gameTable = new GameTable(3, 3);

// Создаем игроков
// Первый параметр - имя игрока, второй - тип фишки (chip)
Player player1 = new Player("Крестик", "X");
Player player2 = new Player("Нолик", "0");

players.add(player1); 
players.add(player2);
```

**Игровой процесс**

Ходят игроки последовательно друг за другом до тех пор пока один из них не выставит свои фишки в ряд (горизонтально, вертикально, или по-диагоналям).

Ага, так, последовательно, друг за другом, пока кто-то не будет признан выигравшим после проверки очередного хода на выполненную/выигрышную комбинацию:

```
// Ссылка на победителя
Player winner = null;

// Индекс текущего игрока
int currentPlayerIndex = 0;

// Цикл будет крутиться до тех пор, пока внутри него игроки будут делать ходы и
// либо один из них не выиграет, либо пока не заполнится игровое поле
while(true) {
    Player player = players.get(currentPlayerIndex);

    if ( gameTable.move( player ) ) {
        // у нас есть победитель
        winner = player;
        break;
    } else if (gameTable.isFull()) {
        break;
    }

    // Если нет победителя и на доске еще есть место для ходов, то
    // меняем индекс текущего игрока, чтобы передать ход другому.
    // Здесь мы увеличиваем индекс на единицу и делим по модулю на 
    // количество игроков, тем самым избегая "выскакивания" индекса за пределы массива    
    currentPlayerIndex = ++currentPlayerIndex % players.size();
}

if ( winner != null ) {
    System.out.print(" Победитель: " + player.getName());
} else {
    System.out.print(" Ничья! ");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за конструктив! Интересное решение. Я реализовал немного по-другому, но Ваш код выглядит лаконичнее, опробую и его тоже. Только интересует строка return this.checkWinCombination(selectedRow, selectedRow); - здесь переменные задаются отдельно посредством ввода двух чисел? Или реализация осуществляется путём присваивания selectedRow = 0 и selectedRow = 0, если игрок ввёл единицу или selectedRow = 1 и selectedRow = 2, если ввёл пятерку, и в цикле сравниваются ячейки  table[selectedRow][selectedRow] со смежными? Или может есть более простой способ?

Comment: @Илья Николаев selectedRow и col вы можете заменить на что-то свое, что вам более подходит. Я бы дал пользователю вводить оба числа самостоятельно

Answer (score 2):

**как сделать поочередный ход?**
можно использовать переменную типа `boolean`, где `false` - первый игрок (крести), а `true` - второй игрок (нолик).
перед каждым ходом - проверяем кто сейчас ходит.
после каждого хода - инвертируем переменную.

**как установить запрет на изменение крестика на нолик и наоборот?**
вариантом может быть создание второй скрытой матрицы, которая будет наполнена изначально одним значение =0.
и когда игрок делает ход, например "крестик в [1][2]", то значение в этой "скрытой" матрице меняется с 0 на 1.
соответственно перед каждый ходом надо проверять, чему равно значение в "скрытой" матрице.

доп.идея (та же суть, другая реализация).
у вас матрица [3][3], а можно сделать [3][3][1] и в последнем хранить точно так же 0 или 1.
то есть

Answer (score 1):

После нескольких часов всё-таки родил своё решение:

```
public class Main {

public static boolean isWin = false;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    int randomPlayer = (int) (Math.random() * 2 + 1);
    if (randomPlayer == 1)
        System.out.println("Player1 ходит первым!" + '\n');
    else System.out.println("Player2 ходит первым!" + '\n');

    System.out.println("Введите число от 1 до 9, чтобы сделать Ваш ход: " + '\n');

    char[][] field = {{'1','2','3'},
                      {'4','5','6'},
                      {'7','8','9'}};

    char crossOrZero;

    int switcher = 0; // переключатель между первым и вторым игроком
    while (true) {

        if (switcher % 2 == 0)
            crossOrZero = 'x';
        else crossOrZero = 'o';

        printField(field);

        int num;
        try {
            num = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()); // запрет ввода символов, отличных от чисел
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Число, только число!");
            continue;
        }

        if (Arrays.deepToString(field).contains(Integer.toString(num)) && num <= 9 && num > 0) {
            switch (num) {
                case 1: field[0][0] = crossOrZero; break;
                case 2: field[0][1] = crossOrZero; break;
                case 3: field[0][2] = crossOrZero; break;
                case 4: field[1][0] = crossOrZero; break;
                case 5: field[1][1] = crossOrZero; break;
                case 6: field[1][2] = crossOrZero; break;
                case 7: field[2][0] = crossOrZero; break;
                case 8: field[2][1] = crossOrZero; break;
                case 9: field[2][2] = crossOrZero; break;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Введите число из оставшихся на поле!");
            continue;
        }

       checkingForMatch(field);

        if (isWin) {
            System.out.println("YOU WIN!!!");
            printField(field);
            break;
        }
        switcher++;
    }
}

public static void printField (char[][] field) { // печать поля

    for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < field[i].length; j++) {
            if (j != 2)
                System.out.print(field[i][j] + "|");
            else System.out.print(field[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void checkingForMatch (char[][] field) { // проверка на совпадение трёх элементов

    for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
        if (field[i][0] == field[i][1] && field[i][0] == field[i][2] || // сравнение по горизонтали
            field[0][i] == field[1][i] && field[0][i] == field[2][i] || // сравнение по вертикали
            field[0][0] == field[1][1] && field[0][0] == field[2][2] || // сравнение по
            field[2][0] == field[1][1] && field[2][0] == field[0][2]) { // диагоналям

            isWin = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```